# AppleScript: Error -15267 Copying to External

Tags: applescript

I recently started AppleScript and wanted to slowly getting into scripting and hoping someone can help me with a block I have ran into. Tried a few things and moving pieces around and changing identifiers but don't know what I should be looking for to change. Hoping someone can help me out and explain my flaws.

**Background Story:** Trying to test a script to back up of a user account home folder to an external drive.

What I have first: drive verification to make sure there is a drive plugged into the computer. Followed by setting source and destination. Then tried compiling an if then statement to single out 2 folders I don't want to be copied over (only focusing on the user folder, but unsure if that is correct and will need that looked at too). I get my error at the duplicate command: "Finder got an error: An item with the same name already exist in this location." However, there is nothing the external so I have no clue what else to do. Any advice would be helpful.

**This is the code I have to start with:**

```
tell application "System Events" to set diskNames to name of every disk

if "Untitled" is in the diskNames then
    display dialog "Disk is mounted" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon 1
else
    display dialog "No disk found" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon 1
end if

tell application "Finder"

    set source_folder to "Macintosh HD:Users:"
    set tar_disk to "Untitled:"

    if source_folder is not {"administrator", "Shared"} then
        with timeout of 3600 seconds -- 2 hours
            duplicate source_folder to tar_disk
        end timeout
    else
        display dialog "No folder detected" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon 1
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to copy only your own home folder with the Finder, you don't have permissions to copy the home folders of other users (except `Shared`).

Basically it's good habit to add Finder specifiers to literal strings representing files, folders and disks for example

```
set tar_disk to disk "Untitled"
```

Since there is a `home` property pointing to the current home folder you can write

```
tell application "Finder"
    set tar_disk to disk "Untitled"

    with timeout of 3600 seconds -- 2 hours
        duplicate home to tar_disk
    end timeout

end tell
```

**There is an important caveat**: The Finder copies only the visible files and folders. If `AppleShowAllFiles` is set to false all files starting with a dot are ignored. To copy the entire home folder something like the shell `rsync` command is the better choice – also for speed reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Really appreciate it. Wanted to test scripting like this first to get the hang of it. rsync is what I will work with next for the same objective. Thanks again!